# StripeJS - Getting Exp Month and Year on Input

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm implementing StripeJS Elements to allow users to add their credit card information in our platform.

As part of our implementation, we want to show some UI to the user when their credit card will expire during a subscription cycle. To do this, we need to pull the expiry month and expiry year from the Card element while the user is typing. I've scoured the Stripe docs, and can't seem to find a way to do this?

Here's my implementation thus far:

```
stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
elements = stripe.elements({
    locale: auto
});

card = elements.create('card', {
    iconStyle: 'solid',
    style: {
      base: {
        iconColor: '#495057',
        color: '#495057',
        fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins, Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',

        ':-webkit-autofill': {
          color: '#fce883',
        },
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#e2e5ec',
        },
      },
      invalid: {
        iconColor: '#FF0000',
        color: '#FF0000',
      },
    },
});

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {

    // this doesn't seem to be capturing keystrokes, or give me any real info about the card

});
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible by using the `change` event, as that'll only expose whether the element is empty and whether it "looks" complete.

You could use stripe.js to first [create a PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method) with the element, and get the [expiry date](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-exp_month) from that PaymentMethod. However this requires your user to fully fill out the elements first.